# How to add additional spring security field for login

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I want to implement user `login/signup using username, password and project (additional field)`. It is working with `username and password` but `unable to implement to add additional field (project)` since I am new to spring security.

1. I am able to signup with `email, username, password and project`.
2. I have added `Project` in `UserPrincipal` as shown in below code.

I need to implement `custom authentication to add project during login` but I am unable to figure out how to proceed further. Can anybody help please? i have already checked other solutions but did not figure out to implement.

Comment: You didn't mention your JWT config and it's crucial here...

Comment: @k-wasilewski I have added it. Kindly check

Comment: Could you be confusing authorization with authentication? `username` and `password` are usually the only things required for identifying(authenticating) the user. To give them access to a particular resource like a project, you need to authorize them.
Some tips on authorization can be found here: https://www.marcobehler.com/guides/spring-security

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you want to just add this `project` info to a User, during login/sign-up.

As @HarshVerma pointed out, in Spring it's only the login and the password you need to autheticate.

You could implement user's `project` as a JWT claim:

```
Jwts.builder()
     .setSubject(Long.toString(userPrincipal.getId()))
     .claim("project", myProject)
     .setIssuedAt(new Date())
     .setExpiration(expiryDate)
     .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, jwtSecret)
     .compact();
```

and then retreive it to authorize accordingly:

```
Claims claims = new DefaultClaims();
    try{
        claims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(jwtSecret).parseClaimsJws(jwt).getBody();
    } catch (SignatureException e){
        // signature exception
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the following changes to the auth controller. Check if `username` owns the `project` before setting the `authentication` in the context. This feels a little hacky though :

```
public class AuthController {
...
@PostMapping("/signin")
    public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateUser(@Valid @RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) {

        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        loginRequest.getUsernameOrEmail(),
                        loginRequest.getPassword()
                        )
                );

        // checking if user owns the project
        if (usernameOwnsProject(username, project)) {
         SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
          String jwt = tokenProvider.generateToken(authentication);
          return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtAuthenticationResponse(jwt));
        } else {
          // throw error 
        }
        
    }
...
}
```